# Programmatically click link with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am testing out a plugin that I am building, but I can't quite get 1 part to work. I am trying to programmatically click a link on the following page(as an example):

```
http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/flyknit-lunar2-running-shoe/pid-830248/pgid-1499411
```

I am trying to click the size button to have the sizes be displayed, but nothing seems to be happening. I am able to change the actual text on the button:

```
$('span.js-selectBox-label').html("Testing");
```

That works, so I know I'm talking to the correct span. However, when I call click, that doesn't seem to do anything. I would expect the size box to pop up as it does when I manually click the sizes button:

```
$('span.js-selectBox-label').click();
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to use jQuery to programmatically select a size. So if someone can suggest a shortcut to doing that, I would be ok with that too.

Comment: Are you suppose to be clicking the <span> or do you have to click the <a> within the span?

Comment: Good question. I will look at that now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're meant to be clicking the `<a>` tag within the `<span>`, then you could try something like this:

```
$('span.js-selectBox-label WHATEVER_THE_A_TAG_IS_CALLED').click()
```

Comment: The span is actually contained within the a tag. The nesting of the divs/spans/a make this incredibly difficult

Comment: You should be clicking on the a tag instead then, forget about the span.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work: $('a.exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown').click();  Everything after the a is the class of the a tag.

Comment: That space in the middle of the a tag there means there are two separate classes used for the a tag. The space in $('  ') means it's accessing something within the first element. Try just using just one of names in your $(''). However class names are dangerous to use because they can be repeated. Ideally, there would be an id for the a tag so then you can be confident you're only grabbing one a tag.

Answer (score 0):

If a click event is attached to this element, then you can programmatically fire it using jQuery's `trigger` method:

```
$('a.exp-pdp-size-dropdown').trigger('click');
```

See documentation here: http://jqapi.com/#p=trigger